# Can I move a 13 year old Wisteria from the ground to a container?

Tags: transplanting, wisteria

My Wisteria has been growing well in its current spot for about 13 years but has become too large for the fence that first supported it.  It measures about 6ft and I would like to re-position it to the front garden where it can climb the front of the house.  At present, it grows happily in a flower bed and and would be transplanted into a large tub or enclosure.  Is any of this possible?

Answer (score 5):

After 13 years, very difficult, not to say impossible. The root spread will be enormous by now, so without heavy lifting gear (crane and tarpaulin or a grab of the sort used for trees), you'll lose most of the roots, which means you're likely to lose the plant.

Comment: If the plant has to be moved then you could dig a trench of three foot diameter around to a depth of a foot or so, wait till spring, trench again a little closer and move it in the fall.

Comment: I agree with kevinsky.  Prune the roots now and overwinter it.  Then move in spring or even fall of next year.  Moving large established plants takes some planning but can be done.  Make sure you keep it watered.