# Transplanting established Wisteria from pots to ground

Tags: containers, transplanting, wisteria

I have two *Wisteria Brachybotrys*, each growing in a 1200 litre tub, on either side of a gazebo.  They are young, purchased in the spring, but have already entwined the trellis walls and the roof of the gazebo.  They are each some 2.5m tall.  The location is southern England and the location is in full sun from mid-morning to dusk.

Looking to the future, I want to know how long these plants can sensibly be kept in these containers before becoming potbound.
The [RHS guidelines](https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/profile?PID=173) indicate that container growth is possible but don't indicate a timeline.

If the expected life in pots is only a few years, I would expect to try to transplant them into the ground.  To do this would require cutting the plants out of the trellis, which, if I must do, I would want to do soon, before they become too entwined.

This is something of the inverse of [this earlier question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/8482/20139)

Should I leave these plants alone?  They're quite healthy and, given the size of the pots, transplanting them will be quite an exercise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your plants already are accustomed to that space.  They should be planted right where they sit.  If you have to undo some of the vines or break them accidentally, no matter.

Please send a picture or two.  You will be amazed at the difference when these plants get planted in the larger body of the garden soil. There will be a lull for sure after planting but make no mistake, your Wisteria needs to be planted in the ground right where they sit.

Do not dig deeper than that root ball.  Keep the subsoil firm beneath those plants.  Do not add any compost, sand...nothing.  They will be fine.  Make dang sure you keep them watered but don't over water.  What have you used for fertilizer?  All plants need fertilizer added in very specific amounts; Less is Best, More is Death and None is Dumb.

Wisteria loves to have their roots stay cool.  Shadier soil as they grow up towards the light. When your Wisteria acclimates to being transplanted you can cut back the watering.

Wisteria when happy and planted in the larger body of the garden soil grows quite fast.  Learn how to prune this vine and soon for control and beauty.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Roots keeping cool is something I hadn't thought of.  The pots get full sun in the afternoon, so presumably the roots get pretty warm.

Comment: What is the reason you want to keep them in pots?  While they are young you should want to get them established in the main body of the garden soil and in the environment they are most used to.